# Reproducing Stata pooled OLS results

Tags: r, stata, plm

I'm trying to reproduce results from Stata. The dataset is an unbalanced panel which looks like

```
  ï..region id year grpmlnr   grppc   cpi
1  region1   1 1998 18245.5 12242.8 167.7
2  region1   1 1999 32060.6 21398.0 140.8
3  region1   1 2000 42074.5 27969.5 120.9
```

The original regression in Stata was pooled OLS of the form `reg y x1 x2 x3 x4` and gave the following output

```
         Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
x1 |  -.0045519   .0070808    -0.64   0.520    -.0184413    .0093376
x2 |  -.1598071   .0345597    -4.62   0.000    -.2275982    -.092016
x3 |   4.08e-06   4.16e-06     0.98   0.327    -4.08e-06    .0000122
x4 |  -.0000874   .0000244    -3.58   0.000    -.0001354   -.0000395
_cons |   .2899655   .0655542     4.42   0.000   .1613767    .4185542

Number of obs = 1489, R=squared = 0.0242, Adj R-squared = 0.0216
```

When I run

```r
pooledols<-plm(y~
                 x1
               + x2
               + x3
               + x4,
               data=dataset, index=c('ï..region', 'year'), model='pooling')

summary(pooledols)
```

I get

```r
Coefficients:
                      Estimate  Std. Error t-value  Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)         1.1228e-02  6.3812e-02  0.1760 0.8603497    
x1                  3.5982e-03  6.7284e-03  0.5348 0.5928858    
x2                  4.3466e-02  3.1060e-03 13.9943 < 2.2e-16 ***
x3                  1.3737e-05  3.9212e-06  3.5033 0.0004732 ***
x4                  -2.7368e-05  2.3573e-05 -1.1610 0.2458259
```

with

```r
number of obs = 1489, R=squared = 0.12554, and Adj R-squared = 0.12319.
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? I'm confident the dataset is the same in both cases. I saw it suggested elsewhere that with random-effects models it matters how Stata and R deal with unbalanced panels, but I'm not sure whether that's relevant here.

Edit: here's a subset of my data, where `x1, x2, x3, x4` match the variables used in the regressions:

`region year    x1          x2          x3  x4  y
RegionA 1998    9.412693    7.316763    655 212 
RegionA 1999    9.412693    4.662889    720 232 0.55836
RegionA 2000    9.412693    3.669467    741 303 0.267817
RegionA 2001    9.412693    3.480852    748 304 0.169225
RegionA 2002    9.412693    3.434518    720 347 0.221187
RegionA 2003    9.412693    3.252523    719 393 0.195911
RegionA 2004    9.412693    2.30941     731 426 0.408409
RegionA 2005    9.412693    2.03653     714 477 0.237577
RegionA 2006    9.412693    1.857329    752 512 0.209052
RegionA 2007    9.412693    1.796764    735 527 0.278823
RegionA 2008    9.412693    1.59614     759 543 0.288872
RegionA 2009    9.412693    1.925464    793 522 -0.04663
RegionA 2010    9.412693    1.685813    779 508 0.267205
RegionA 2011    9.412693    1.570235    767 478 0.241406
RegionA 2012    9.412693    1.689142    787 446 0.068759
RegionA 2013    9.412693    1.819899    810 420 0.03955
RegionA 2014    9.412693    1.859676    814 382 0.083057
RegionA 2015    9.412693    1.860045    806 342 0.11043
RegionA 2016    9.412693    1.921366    822 326 0.048621
RegionA 2017    9.412693    1.911606    823 316 0.074802
RegionB 1998    8.94365     10.81936    633 129 
RegionB 1999    8.94365     7.110605    698 152 0.428163
RegionB 2000    8.94365     5.014219    665 192 0.393189
RegionB 2001    8.94365     4.521011    652 208 0.21136
RegionB 2002    8.94365     4.237961    636 276 0.227971
RegionB 2003    8.94365     4.373059    651 301 0.167702
RegionB 2004    8.94365     3.992342    659 320 0.165888
RegionB 2005    8.94365     3.276585    648 345 0.280323
RegionB 2006    8.94365     2.853214    660 392 0.219669
RegionB 2007    8.94365     3.031803    661 401 0.233179
RegionB 2008    8.94365     2.598884    656 457 0.210191
RegionB 2009    8.94365     2.773871    638 472 0.011586
RegionB 2010    8.94365     2.618205    650 443 0.157882
RegionB 2011    8.94365     2.474298    644 410 0.178349
RegionB 2012    8.94365     2.257853    644 387 0.182941
RegionB 2013    8.94365     2.362653    638 336 0.06543
RegionB 2014    8.94365     2.35502     635 320 0.108892
RegionB 2015    8.94365     2.308449    624 282 0.119917
RegionB 2016    8.94365     2.607521    625 252 0.038878
RegionB 2017    8.94365     2.583059    612 223 0.096383
RegionC 1998    9.143153    7.710033    771 120 
RegionC 1999    9.143153    4.82562     810 139 0.50267
RegionC 2000    9.143153    4.112946    798 184 0.309938
RegionC 2001    9.143153    3.384044    785 181 0.254107
RegionC 2002    9.143153    3.639285    808 280 0.192077
RegionC 2003    9.143153    3.58782     796 302 0.214723
RegionC 2004    9.143153    2.960462    806 319 0.190094
RegionC 2005    9.143153    2.528599    809 361 0.165926
RegionC 2006    9.143153    2.252368    792 393 0.26823`

Edit 2: These are the results for the first regression, identical to Nick Cox's:

```
lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4, data = replicate)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.23488 -0.06966  0.00142  0.05492  0.20161 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -1.792e+00  8.772e-01  -2.043   0.0475 *  
x1           1.865e-01  1.149e-01   1.623   0.1122    
x2           8.823e-02  1.989e-02   4.437 6.72e-05 ***
x3          -6.175e-05  3.271e-04  -0.189   0.8512    
x4           1.995e-04  2.242e-04   0.890   0.3786`
```

Comment: ... and `plm(., model = "pooling")` will give you the same result. You must have mixed up your data in your first try.

Answer (score 0):

49 observations (rows) were posted; 3 have missing values for `y`. This is a plain regression from Stata with no attention whatsoever to panel structure (let alone any time variable). `_cons` is the estimated intercept. I also list the 3 observations automatically excluded. Someone else may want to post R results.

```
. regress y x1 x2 x3 x4

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =        46
-------------+----------------------------------   F(4, 41)        =      7.41
       Model |  .287208881         4   .07180222   Prob > F        =    0.0001
    Residual |  .397187973        41  .009687512   R-squared       =    0.4197
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.3630
       Total |  .684396854        45  .015208819   Root MSE        =    .09843

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           y |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
          x1 |   .1864634   .1148715     1.62   0.112    -.0455244    .4184511
          x2 |   .0882264   .0198852     4.44   0.000     .0480674    .1283854
          x3 |  -.0000618   .0003271    -0.19   0.851    -.0007223    .0005988
          x4 |   .0001995   .0002242     0.89   0.379    -.0002532    .0006522
       _cons |  -1.791928   .8772392    -2.04   0.048    -3.563548   -.0203073
------------------------------------------------------------------------------


. l if !e(sample)

     +-----------------------------------------------+
     |  region         x1         x2    x3    x4   y |
     |-----------------------------------------------|
  1. | RegionA   9.412693   7.316763   655   212   . |
 21. | RegionB    8.94365   10.81936   633   129   . |
 41. | RegionC   9.143153   7.710033   771   120   . |
     +-----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I just got the same results for this regression, would you be willing to have a look at a panel regression if I added the years?